# How to Determine What Files are being Used by Program

Tags: process-explorer, monitoring

I am running a application on my server. The users connect to this application using a BDE SQL connector.

The application uses a "runtime" to run on client PC's. The "runtime" files are located in the *Windows* directory. Because the users only have restricted access to the *Windows* directory, the "runtime" causes problems.

I like to give the users the needed permissions on those "runtime" files. How do I locate all the files where read- or write-access is denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good tools for this kind of job are [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653) and especially [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645).

A good filter to start would be `Path begins with C:\Windows`, if the default filter is showing too much information.